# CollectionView in tableViewCell data display

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView embedded in each tableViewCell. On each tableViewWillDisplayCell event I set correct dataSource for my collectionView and then reload data in collectionView.

Here is the code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let c = cell as! CustomTableViewCell
    c.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

CustomTableViewCell.swift:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var collectionView: indexedCollectionView!

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(5, 5)
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
    self.collectionView = indexedCollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: collectionViewCellIdentifier as String)
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.collectionView)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.collectionView.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
}

func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate delegate: protocol<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>, indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    self.collectionView.dataSource = delegate
    self.collectionView.delegate = delegate
    self.collectionView.indexPath = indexPath
    self.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}

}
```

TableViewController.swift:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    let tableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: collectionView.tag, inSection: 0))
    var rect: CGRect?

    var label: UILabel = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18.0)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableViewCell!.frame.width * 0.2, tableViewCell!.frame.height)
        rect = cell.bounds
        label.frame = rect!
        label.text = events[collectionView.tag].category
        break
    case 1:
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(tableViewCell!.frame.width * 0.2, 0, tableViewCell!.frame.width * 0.3, tableViewCell!.frame.height)
        rect = cell.bounds
        label.frame = rect!
        label.text = events[collectionView.tag].event
        break
    case 2:
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(tableViewCell!.frame.width * 0.5, 0, tableViewCell!.frame.width * 0.26, tableViewCell!.frame.height)
        rect = cell.bounds
        label.frame = rect!
        label.text = events[collectionView.tag].location
        break
    case 3:
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(tableViewCell!.frame.width * 0.76, 0, tableViewCell!.frame.width * 0.12, tableViewCell!.frame.height)
        rect = cell.bounds
        label.frame = rect!
        label.text = events[collectionView.tag].date
        break
    case 4:
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(tableViewCell!.frame.width * 0.88, 0, tableViewCell!.frame.width * 0.12, tableViewCell!.frame.height)
        rect = cell.bounds
        label.frame = rect!
        label.text = events[collectionView.tag].time
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    cell.addSubview(label)
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

    return cell
}
```

When application launch everything looks fine ([screenshot](http://oi58.tinypic.com/29c5mde.jpg)) but when I scroll my tableView it become to fire tableView willDisplayCell event again for each cell which fires their collectionView's reloadData.

But it doesn't works well ([screenshot](http://oi61.tinypic.com/zwneig.jpg)). Can someone help me with my problem?

UPDATE:

I have tried to remake my code but i've got a problem. Here is my whole code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {//, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var events: [Event] = [
    Event(category: "GAA - Football Campionship", event: "Round 4A Munster Final Runner up v Round 3A Winner", location: "Semple Stadium - Thurles", date: "7/12/15", time: "2:00pm"),
    Event(category: "Football", event: "Round 4A Munster", location: "Thurles", date: "7/2/15", time: "All day"),
    Event(category: "Golf - 4 Majors", event: "U.S. Open Day 4 ( Final Day)", location: "Oakmont Country Club, Pennsylvania", date: "7/12/15", time: ""),
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //self.tableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .None
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return events.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: CustomTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = CustomTableViewCell.CreateCustomCell()
    }
    cell!.event = events[indexPath.row]
    cell!.size = CGSize(width: cell!.frame.width, height: cell!.frame.height)
    cell!.collectionView.reloadData()
    cell!.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell!
}

//    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
//        let c = cell as! CustomTableViewCell
//        c.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, indexPath: indexPath)
//    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var cellHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    let screenWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

    var question: NSString = events[indexPath.row].category
    var size = CGSizeMake(screenWidth * 0.2, 9999)
    var textRect = question.boundingRectWithSize(size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18.0)!], context: nil)
    size = textRect.size
    cellHeight = size.height

    question = events[indexPath.row].event
    size = CGSizeMake(screenWidth * 0.3, 9999)
    textRect = question.boundingRectWithSize(size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18.0)!], context: nil)
    size = textRect.size
    if cellHeight < size.height {
        cellHeight = size.height
    }

    question = events[indexPath.row].location
    size = CGSizeMake(screenWidth * 0.3, 9999)
    textRect = question.boundingRectWithSize(size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18.0)!], context: nil)
    size = textRect.size
    if cellHeight < size.height {
        cellHeight = size.height
    }

    question = events[indexPath.row].date
    size = CGSizeMake(screenWidth * 0.1, 9999)
    textRect = question.boundingRectWithSize(size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18.0)!], context: nil)
    size = textRect.size
    if cellHeight < size.height {
        cellHeight = size.height
    }

    question = events[indexPath.row].time
    size = CGSizeMake(screenWidth * 0.1, 9999)
    textRect = question.boundingRectWithSize(size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18.0)!], context: nil)
    size = textRect.size
    if cellHeight < size.height {
        cellHeight = size.height
    }

    return cellHeight
}
}
```

CustomTableViewCell.swift:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

//var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var event: Event?
var size: CGSize?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    println("awake")

    var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(5, 5)
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    //self.collectionView = indexedCollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.registerClass(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    var cNib:UINib? = UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.registerNib(cNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
    collectionView.frame = self.bounds
    //self.contentView.addSubview(self.collectionView)

}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

//        var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
//        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
//        layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(5, 5)
//        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
//        self.collectionView = indexedCollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
//        self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: collectionViewCellIdentifier as String)
//        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
//        self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
//        self.contentView.addSubview(self.collectionView)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

//    override func layoutSubviews() {
//        super.layoutSubviews()
//        self.collectionView.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
//    }

//    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate delegate: protocol<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>, indexPath: NSIndexPath){
//        self.collectionView.dataSource = delegate
//        self.collectionView.delegate = delegate
//        self.collectionView.indexPath = indexPath
//        self.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
//        self.collectionView.reloadData()
//    }

// MARK: - Collection view data source

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: CustomCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    //let tableViewCell = tableView!.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: collectionView.tag, inSection: 0))
    var rect: CGRect?

    var label: UILabel = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18.0)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size!.width * 0.2, size!.height)
        rect = cell.bounds
        label.frame = rect!
        label.text = event!.category
        break
    case 1:
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(size!.width * 0.2, 0, size!.width * 0.3, size!.height)
        rect = cell.bounds
        label.frame = rect!
        label.text = event!.event
        break
    case 2:
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(size!.width * 0.5, 0, size!.width * 0.26, size!.height)
        rect = cell.bounds
        label.frame = rect!
        label.text = event!.location
        break
    case 3:
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(size!.width * 0.76, 0, size!.width * 0.12, size!.height)
        rect = cell.bounds
        label.frame = rect!
        label.text = event!.date
        break
    case 4:
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(size!.width * 0.88, 0, size!.width * 0.12, size!.height)
        rect = cell.bounds
        label.frame = rect!
        label.text = event!.time
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    cell.addSubview(label)
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

    return cell
}

class func CreateCustomCell() -> CustomTableViewCell
{
    var nibElements: Array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)
    var item: AnyObject?
    for item in nibElements
    {
        if item is UITableViewCell
        {
            return item as! CustomTableViewCell
        }
    }
    return item as! CustomTableViewCell
}
}
```

CustomCollectionViewCell.swift

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}
}
```

Also, in storyboard I added a collectionView to my tableViewCell, connected it to outlet variable and set CustomCollectionCell class to collectionCell in storyboard.

But when I launch the app it thrown an exception on this line in tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath:

> 2015-07-16 13:29:00.965 CollectionViewInTableViewCell[4241:1005396] Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSUnknownKeyException, reason: [CollectionViewInTableViewCell.CustomTableViewCell 0x126e12440 setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key collection.'

Comment: check my answer hear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159099/uicollectionview-cells-with-images-inside-uitableview-prototype/30164764#30164764

Comment: how can I pass my data from controller to customTableViewCell to enter data to collectionViewCells?

Comment: Just add a data property to your custom cell and set it in the controller (cellForRowAtIndexPath).

Comment: Ok, i'll try to and tell u if something goes wrong.

Comment: @mikle94 see in my sample code in `cellForAtIndexPath` method i am passing data to cell and in cell it will be used by the collection view for example  `cell?.folderCount = cardCountArray[indexPath.section]`

Comment: I've tried, check my updated answer please(

Comment: @Shan I have created new project just to try your example, i created customTableViewCell with xib and customCollectionViewCell with xib. Then i add a label to customCollectionViewCell.xib and make an outlet to customCollectionViewCell.swift. Then I added a collectionView to customTableViewCell.swift and make an outlet to this cell and drag delegate and datasource to this cell. The rest of the code i just copypasted. But when I launch my app it crashes on this line of code: foldersCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = aFlowLayout. Exception:unexpectedly found nil while unwrap an Optional value.

Comment: @Shan Also, I added a tableView in my storyboard to ViewController. Then in viewDidLoad wrote these lines of code: tableView.dataSource = self tableView.delegate = self and set tableCellIdentifier as "CELL". Where did I do wrong?

Comment: @Shan If u want, I can update my answer with the whole code of your example. Coz I really don't what's wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Your `CustomTableViewCell` has to implement the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and the cell itself has to be linked to the delegate and datasource when adding it to the table view.