# How to make Hozirontal UITableView with Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, collectionview

I'm a new to swift, and I'm making a view showing list of films look like appstore main screen(horizontal UITableView) so I have a problem when I customize UITableViewCell. The cells were not showing in UITableView. I don't know why? and how to fix it! Here is my code:
movieViewController:

```
class movieViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var mCollection: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var mTable: UITableView!
var categories = ["Phim Đang Hot", "Phim Lẻ", "Phim Bộ", "Phim Hài", "Phim Kinh Dị"]
@IBOutlet weak var btnMenu: UIBarButtonItem!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btnMenu.target = self.revealViewController()
    btnMenu.action = Selector("revealToggle:")

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 200

    self.mTable.registerClass(CategoryRow.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return categories[section]
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categories.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CategoryRow
    return cell
}
}
```

And CategoryRow.swift:

```
class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}
extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 12
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("videoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VideoCell
    return cell
}}
extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 4
    let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 5
    let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
    let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
}
```

And this is my VideoCell:

```
class VideoCell : UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

and my StoryBoard:

[image]

and my Sreen: 
[image]

Comment: Is this you are looking for? http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/sv02.gif

Comment: yes i am, but i can't do it.

Comment: see this might help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159099/uicollectionview-cells-with-images-inside-uitableview-prototype/30164764#30164764

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting your collectionView's delegate and dataSource to your tableViewCell's cell class from storyboard.

Comment: i checked 4 times , deleted it and do again 3 times , but nothing was change.

Comment: you need to call reload collection view method i.e [collectionView reloaDatd] from your cellForRowAtIndexPath of table view delegate method.

Comment: can you help me in teamviewer?

Comment: it not possible with teamviewer right now.
Try use this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CategoryRow

cell.collectionView?.reloadData()

    return cell
}

Comment: Have set all this properties of collection view,
1. scrollDirection = horizontal  
2. minimumLineSpacing 
3. minimumInteritemSpacing

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for misreading the question.

It looks like it's possible that your collectionView doesn't have its delegate set as the cell. Change your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to this, which will ensure you're at least producing your horizontal cells.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CategoryRow
     cell.collectionView.delegate = cell
     return cell
}
```

Comment: i do it look like a tutorial : http://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/
But i don't know how to fixit

Comment: He is trying to add collectionView inside tableView. which make it so complicated.

Comment: i added your code and have an error:
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: It sounds like your collectionView is not actually connected to your CategoryRow tableViewCell in storyboard.

Comment: can you help me? in teamviewer?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your identifiers and outlets (see image below).

[image]

When you start wiring up API calls to get your video images, you might want to check out this [blog post](http://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/scrolling-in-two-directions-like-netflix-part-2-making-api-calls/) which is a part 2 of the tutorial but using AlamoFire to call a sample API and download some images.

I noticed you are using a slide-out menu too. The pan gesture might conflict with your horizontally sliding collection view cells. So you might want to use a **Screen Edge Pan Gesture Recognizer** instead. Or you can check out this [blog post](http://www.thorntech.com/2016/03/ios-tutorial-make-interactive-slide-menu-swift/) on creating a customizable interactive slide-out menu.

Finally, it's asking a lot to make you integrate all these tutorials without knowing for sure whether it would work. So I went ahead and created a new [GitHub branch called evan](https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/HorizontalScrollingCollectionView/tree/evan) that incorporates the horizontal scroller, API calls, and interactive slide-out menu. This is what it looks like:

[image]